# How to show message during initial loading of gwt application?

Tags: gwt, loading

I want to display a message (please wait...) or animated gif before the initial entire loading of my gwt application.

Can you give me a full example please.

Thanks

Comment: how much time it takes for loading?is it because of any service? you can mask the onModuleLoad widget and on completion of service unmask the module load widget

Comment: just one minute or more a little. I'm newbie so can you show an example of how I can mask the onModuleLoad ? (isn't it a function ? not a widget I think )

Comment: ... I didn't ask any service at startup, but just initialize the UI with widgets.

Answer (score 3):

Because the GWT app is not yet loaded, you have to do it in pure HTML/CSS and/or JS in your HTML host page.  The easiest is to just put it in your `<body>` and when the GWT app loads it starts by cleaning that "loading" message (e.g. `Document.get().getElementByid("loading").removeFromParent()`)

Another possibility is to use [code-splitting](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html): make a first fragment that's as small as possible and will display your "loading" message, and load the rest of the app in the background. In the `RunAsyncCallback`, hide your "loading" message.

That said, if you feel the need to display such a "loading" message, then IMO you have a bigger problem than finding how to display it (and if you struggle to find how to display one, you're in bad shape to build an app that people will enjoy using; fortunately, this is fixable: keep learning!).

Comment: please can you give an small code illustrating with code splitting ? thanks